# React useState not working with conditional operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

This is my codes in React.

```js
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [like, setLike] = useState(dataObj.likedCount); // like === 4
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(like);
    console.log(click);
    return setClick(!click) ? setLike(like - 1) : setLike(like + 1);
  };

return (
 <Like onClick={onClick}>{like}</Like>
)
```

And this is console page.
[image]

my trouble is that 'like number' is only increasing, not decreasing. 
Even if boolean is changing, true to false.
I can't find anything wrong on my codes.... :((

Answer (score 3):

You're using the return value of `setClick`. The setter function from [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) doesn't have a documented return value. Experimentation suggests it always returns `undefined`. So you can't rely on the return value from `setClick`.

If your goal is to use the value of `!click`, do so directly:

```
setClick(!click);
if (!click) {
    setLike(like - 1); // Or you may want + 1 here
} else {
    setLike(like + 1); // Or you may want - 1 here
}
```

or

```
setClick(!click);
setLike(like + (click ? 1 : -1)); // Again, you may want to swap 1 and -1,
                                  // depending on whether you want to use the
                                  // old value or the new one
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notice points:

- Use state instead of `setClick(!click)` for conditional operator
- do not return in `onClick()`, use props **value** (checked) to make it fully controlled

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [like, setLike] = useState(dataObj.likedCount);
  const onClick = () => {
    setLike(like + (click ? -1 : 1)); // status before click been used here
    setClick(!click);
  };

return (
 <Like onClick={onClick} value={click}>{like}</Like>
)
```